# How do you derive the given eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this tridiagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

In a numerical analysis [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1305253663)'s section on finite differences for parabolic PDE's, [this tridiagonal matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiAjr.png) is given when discussing the backward-difference method. It is provided without explanation that this matrix has eigenvalues

$\mu_i = 1 + 4\lambda\left(\sin{\dfrac{i\pi}{2m}} \right)^2$ for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, m-1$
with corresponding eigenvectors $\bf{v}^{\left(i\right)}$, where $v_j^{\left(i\right)}=\sin{\dfrac{ij\pi}{m}}$

How do you go about deriving these eigenvalues and eigenvectors by hand for this matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the matrix you consider is of shape $(m-1) \times (m-1)$.

There are two answers to your question :

1. If the textbook gives you the basis and the eigenvectors, you can check that it works. (In general, when you have to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, a way is to guess them - I mean, as long as you can do it, of course.)
2. In this case, you can write your matrix as : $M = I_n + \lambda J$ where $J$ is a matrix with $2$ on the diagonal, $-1$ on the upper and lower diagonal, $0$ elsewhere. Since $I_n$ is invariant by any change of basis, you only need to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $J$.

In order to find the eigenvectors of $J$, you can notice that it has a lot of structure. It could have more if you add a $-1$ in the upper-right corner and lower-left corner : we will actually consider a system with shape $m \times m$, adding these values in the corner and try to find eigenvectors such that the added coefficient is $0$. Denote the added coefficient $x_0$. An eigenvalue $\mu$ with its eigenvector $(x_0, ..., x_{m-1})$ satisfies :

$$ (2 - \mu) x_j = x_{j-1} + x_{j+1} $$

for every $j$, with the subscript being understood modulo $m$. The point is that, if $x_0 = 0$, then $(x_1, ..., x_{m-1})$ is an eigenvector for your initial matrix. This is read as : multiplication of the eigenvector by a factor ($2 - \mu$) is the same as adding a forward and a backward translation of the coefficients. Translations are hard to control in physical world, but become easy when you go in Fourier's world : set

$$ y_j = \sum_{k = 0}^{m-1} \exp\left(-\frac{2 i \pi k j}{m}\right) x_k $$

so that :

$$ (2 - \mu) y_j = \left( \exp\left(\frac{2 i \pi j}{m}\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{2 i \pi j}{m}\right) \right) y_j = 2 y_j \cos \frac{2 \pi j}{m} $$

And so you must have for each $j$ either $y_j = 0$ or $2 - \mu = 2 \cos \frac{2 \pi j}{m} $. By applying the inverse Fourier transform, you find eigenvectors $X^{(j)} = (\exp( \frac{2 i \pi k j}{m}))_{k = 0, ..., m-1}$, associated with $\mu_j = 4 \sin^2 \frac{2 \pi j}{m}$, $j = 0, ..., m-1$. To recover real-valued eigenvectors, note that $J$ is real and thus, if $X$ is an eigenvector, so is $\overline{X}$. Therefore, for $j = 1, ..., m-1$, by considering $\frac{1}{2i}(X^{(j)} + \overline{X}^{(j)})$ (note that this is $0$ if $j = 0$), you find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues that you were looking for ($X^{(j)}_0 = 0$ so that the extended system is actually equivalent to the initial one).

At the end of it, I suspect the objective of the book was just to give you the answer without trying to see how to find them. (But maybe I'm wrong and there exists a more easy way.)